# PHP Fgets(STDIN) with IF statement

Tags: php, function, fgets

I want to look if the Word is a palindrome but I don't know why I can't **if** statement a **fgets**??

Here is the code:

```
$word = fgets(STDIN);

if ($word == strrev($word)) {

  print("The word is palindrome");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the newline character is included in the output of `fgets()`.

Try this:

```php
$word = trim(fgets(STDIN));

if ($word == strrev($word)) {
  print("The word is palindrome");
}
```

...now it should work as intended, because we `trim()` the word first.